# Want to add html domain to $url_activation - Should be easy?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have an email with an activation link set up. however, the activation link is missing some part of my URL. so it gives "/subcategory/activate?123". however it should be: "http://example.com/subcategory/activate?123". so the first bit is missing.

i have tried within my PHP file to add: "http://example.com/$user_activation_url

however, this did not work.

here is the source of how $user_activation_url is defined.

```
$user_activation_url = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gzd_customer_activation_url', add_query_arg( array( 'activate' => $user_activation )
```

Here is the PHP template of the email where the $user_activation_url is used.

```
<p><a class="wc-button button" href="<?php echo esc_attr( $user_activation_url );?>"><?php _e( 'Activate your account', 'woocommerce-germanized' );?></a></p>
```

I would appreciate anyone with PHP wisedom to provide some tips.

Answer (score 0):

non-portable-answer:

```
<p><a class="wc-button button" href="http://example.org<?php echo esc_attr( $user_activation_url );?>"><?php _e( 'Activate your account', 'woocommerce-germanized' );?></a></p>
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

portable answer is probably

```
<p><a class="wc-button button" href="<?php echo get_site_url().esc_attr( $user_activation_url );?>"><?php _e( 'Activate your account', 'woocommerce-germanized' );?></a></p>
```

also I don't see how your first approach didn't work ...